# Get directory containing the currently executed batch script

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, batch, path, windows-command-prompt

I use `%0` in batch file to get the containing directory of the batch file but the result is :-

`c:\folder1\folder2\batch.bat`

I want just directory, without batch file name, like this :-

`c:\folder1\folder2\`

How can I do it? Maybe I should filter the path. If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: When using %0 in a batch file as part of a command line you should use %0\..\RestOfStuff. The double dot takes it back past the filename.

Comment: The directory containing the currently executed script is not necessarily the same as the current working directory (CD)! I edited the question accordingly - it now avoids the term of "current directory".

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
%~p0
```

Will return the path only.

```
%~dp0
```

Will return the drive+path.

More info on the subject can be found on [Microsoft's site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/call#batch-parameters).

Information about this syntax can also be found in the help for the **for** command by executing `for /?` on a Windows OS.

Comment: As another reference source, the same list of variable substitutions is also shown when you type `for /?`

Comment: %~dp0 gives the directory of the executing batch file. If the batch file is in a different directory, you get that other directory. %CD% always gives you the current directory.

Comment: @MihaiDanila, no, that is not what OP asked.

Comment: Actually I got to this question while searching for a way to get the *current* directory. This was the first hit on Google. The title obviously says *current* directory, although you're right about the content. We're both right, but I think lain and I are more right about what the question actually conveys, in spite of what was intended by it. It's why I've upped lain's answer... The question title should be renamed to be in sync with the question itself.

Comment: @Mihai, I have edited the question accordingly, avoiding the term "current directory" completely.

Comment: Probably title of the article in the link could have been supplied, since the link is no more valid.....

Answer (score 17):

The current directory is held in %CD%

Comment: %CD% reture the path which you execute the batch from it not where the batch file exist

Comment: @Mohammad: Indeed, it is the *current* directory. The other one is the directory where the batch file is. Those two are not the same and your question asks explicitly for this one. So please edit it if that is not what you mean.

Comment: %CD% returns the current path of the batch file but fails when we execute batch file as an administrator. When we run batch file as an administrator then it returns path of System32.
So better option is to use %~dp0 for complete path

Comment: %~dp0 gives the directory of the executing batch file. If the batch file is in a different directory, you get that other directory. %CD% always gives you the current directory.

Comment: For the reader's reference - the question was originally using the term "current directory" while meaning the directory containing the script - this is now fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Some expressions that effect the filename:

`~f0` will give the fully qualified file name.
`~dpnx0` will give the same as `~f0`, but this shows you that you can break it down into parts: d=drive   p=path   n=name   x=extension

Answer (score 1):

use
chdir command

Option 1:

```
chdir
```

Option 2:

```
echo %CD%
```

Comment: Same here: This was not the OP's intention - the question is now clearer.